# Ubuntu 20.04 Wine: WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 122

Tags: ubuntu, crash, wine

I am currently using Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 to try and launch a Windows program (a game called BlackDesert). During the splash screen, the program however crashes. The following is printed on the terminal:

```
2021-03-14 13:10:34 [ERROR  ] The registry could not be read.
[0314/131035:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(153)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 122
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 00000000 at address 7D329F8A (thread 0043), starting debugger...
```

The answers I have found on the internet so far have not helped. Does anyone know what the error entails? (Perhaps I am missing some packages? I tried installing a bunch but it hasn't solved a thing.)

Either way, thanks for the help!

Comment: hey did you solve your problem?

Comment: @SuperNoob nope :c